# Reading a text file and printing out average of a large set of numbers

Tags: java

I have an assignment for my Computer Science class: Create a class that reads a .txt file and prints out the average of all the integers inside.

I'm extremely stuck and I keep getting a "null(in java.util.Scanner)" error, any guidance or help will be extremely appreciated.

here is my code:

```
public static void main() {
    public static void main() {
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner in ;
        try { in = new Scanner(file);
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                int i = in.nextInt();
                int sum = i;
                int x = sum;
                System.out.print(sum / x);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have your file in the right place...

Comment: if you are unsure just put the full path of the file location , eg. starting from C:/.../.../.../numbers.txt ... Anyway from your code doesnt *i=sum=x* ?

Answer (score 1):

> Try putting this in your `main` method :

```
new File(getClass().getResource("numbers.txt").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm().replace("file:", ""));
```

**Update :**
Your file should be in the same package where your class is in